# Continuous Android Background Service

Tags: java, android, background-service

I'm interested in finding out whether it's possible to implement the following:

1) Run a service every 24 hours at a specified time.

2) Launch a method from the service that does something.

I'm assuming that I will have to run a background service, but I don't want the user to have to initiate it in any way. It should be running constantly from the moment the user logs in the first time, and cannot be disabled. Could I use Android AlarmManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and disable the alarm response?

Answer (score 1):

You can request the permission for `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` for it. But you can not enforce this onto the user, he may stop the app and the service forcefully.
You don't have to notify the user if a service is running or starting, this is optional but not advisable e.g. unknown battery / network consumption.

Comment: Luckily it's a private application for a small group of friends, so it's a specifically requested feature but I agree with you. Looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going to Alaram Manager you can use handler to perform your task every 24 hours...And the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED would only be triggered if the device is rebooted, hence start the service also during login...Whatever be the service it would be destroyed manually...